# How to test Image widgets source path in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I have the following setup:

```
return Container(
      child: widget.searchResult.companyLogoUrl.isEmpty
          ? Image.asset('assets/images/missing-company-logo.png')
          : Image.network(widget.searchResult.companyLogoUrl),
    )
```

And now I want to test that the missing logo image is loaded when no url is provided.
How can I get the source url or local file after obtain the Image widget in a test?

```
testWidgets('given', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(createSearchResultCard(mockResponse));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      final Image image = find.byType(Image).evaluate().single.widget as Image;
      final String source = image. // How do I get the file source?
      expect(...)
    });
```

Is there a way to tell which picture has been loaded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check what the image provider is with the `image` property of the `Image` widget class. From there you can extract individual properties:

```dart
String source;
if(image.image is AssetImage) {
  source = image.image.assetName;
} else if(image.image is NetworkImage) {
  source = image.image.url;
}
```

You could expand his to include more possible image providers as needed.

Comment: It works.
I had to typecast image.image once more in the if case, but after that it was smooth sailing.

Answer (score 3):

You can also check the source path of the image with

```dart
expect(find.image(const AssetImage(imagePath)), findsOneWidget);
```

for network images I believe something like this could work

```dart
expect(find.image(const NetworkImage(url)), findsOneWidget);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to test images built with Image.asset() constructor?

Comment: I beilieve with `expect(find.image(const AssetImage(imagePath)), findsOneWidget);` you should be able to test it